# PHP script access a directory that is otherwise 'deny all' (Via .htaccess)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, download, glob

I'm trying to get a php script to list the contents of a backup directory that is protected using a 'deny all' command in a .htaccess file.

The reasoning behind this being a backup plugin for wordpress is only available to Administrators and I'd like to give a lower ranked user the ability to download their backups from online (via a simple dashboard widget).

You can find the code I'm using below, and it trips up when encountering a 403 error because of the htaccess file.

```
//define the directory (this is where the backup plugin store the .zip files)
$directory = site_url() . "/wp-content/backups/";

//display the generated directory for testing
echo '<b>Scanning: </b>' . $directory . '</br></br>';

//display a link to a test.zip I know exists for testing
echo '<b>Manual Link: </b> <a href="' . $directory . 'test.zip" target="_blank">test.zip</a></br></br>';

//get all files in the directory with a .zip extension.
$files = glob($directory . "*.zip");

//print each file name as a download link
foreach($files as $file){
    echo '<a href="' . $file . '">' . $file . '</a> </br>';
}
```

Any help you could provide would be most helpful.

Thanks,
Andy.

**Update on code so that glob works properly**

```
//Define the backup folder location
$backup_location = "wp-content/backups/";

//Set the file directory for glob
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $backup_location;

//Prints the directory for testing purposes
echo '<b>Scanning: </b>' . $directory . '</br></br>';

//Filter the discovered files
$files = glob($directory . "*.*");

//Echo the filtered files
foreach($files as $file){
    echo '<a href="' . site_url() . '/' . $backup_location . basename($file) . '">' . basename($file) . '</a> </br>';
}
```

Comment: It's a WordPress variable that returns the site url (defined in WP backend). Though it seems from the other comments that glob doesn't work via url's.

Comment: Yes, that's true, glob doesnt work via HTTP. Use a local path instead. htaccess does not restrict access via filesystem, so you shouldn't get any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently just providing links to files the user doesn't have access to. This will not work without adding any rights.

What would work in this set-up is to actually serve the files to the user, using your current page.

What you basically do is make the php read the file (it has access to that file), send the user a header and then the content. Use code like the example from the php manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';

if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. As I'm generating the filenames based on what glob returns, there may be more than one file. How would I use this script to display a download link?

Comment: I would use the first script to make the links, but link them to a file with above script and a get parameter (`/site/downloadfile.php?file=yourfilename`). make some checks to make certain only the files you want can be served, but in the end use the `$file = $_GET['file']` to get your filename.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
 $directory = site_url() . "/wp-content/backups/";
```

You cannot do directory listings over HTTP. That does not work (regardless of access restrictions). You need to run `glob()` etc. on local directories.

```
 $directory = "./wp-content/backups/";
```

It says right so on the [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) manual page:

> **Note:** This function will not work on remote files as the file to be examined must be accessible via the server's filesystem.

Comment: Thanks. I've altered my code to reflect this behaviour. It doesn't get around the access issue, but it doe's stop me from falsely claiming the code would work otherwise ;) (see update on mail Q for code)

Comment: No, idea what you're saying. But direct download links will obviously fail unless you implement an access wrapper as #Nanne explained.